# uBlock Origin : Cross-site cosmetic filtering?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, adblock, ublock-origin

Is there a way to block cosmetic elements on multiple sites. For example on StackExchange, I would like to block

```
##.site-footer--container
##.site-header
###left-sidebar
```

But, I don't want ot just block them on a subdomain of stackexchange, I would like to block them on all sites on stackexchange, for example

```
*.stackexchange.com
```

However, a rule like

```
*.stackexchange.com##.site-header
```

does not work, but a rule like

```
 dba.stackexchange.com##.site-header
```

Will work, (though on just the `dba.` subdomain)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the regex patterns for uBlock are not anchored, so you can do

```
stackexchange.com###left-sidebar
stackexchange.com##.site-header
stackexchange.com##.site-footer--container
```

To trim down the bloated Stack Exchange sites.